# ReactJs React Router - Window offset

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React-Router with BrowserHistory in my app. For some reason( I'm somehow sure it is something to do with HistoryApi used by React-Router ) I can't get page offset ( X and Y are both '0').

Simple call like the one below doesn't do anything

```
window.scrollBy(0, 200)
```

Did someone experience same thing? I don't need to store it in store or something, only to scroll to an element on the page.

Comment: To answer your first question: I've a react app running right now with react-router and `scrollBy` works fine here.

Comment: Thanks ivarni! You are right, I've actually tested this in other app and it's fine there

Comment: Did you ever figure out what this issue was? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @bgmaster well, I worked around this by offseting div that acts as a main content area in our app.